# SendGrid API for creating and sending Marketing Campaign fails as Unsubscribe Tag is missing

Tags: c#, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am developing a C# console application in order to create and send a Campaign to the recipients. To accomplish this I have been using SendGrid Web API V3.

Here is my C# code:

```
var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_SENDGRID_API_KEY");
var sendGridClient = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

var campaign = new Campaign
{
    Categories = new string[] { }, 
    UnsubscribeUrl = "",
    HtmlContent = File.ReadAllText("Template/Contacts.html"),
    IpPool = "",
    SenderId = 339919,
    ListIds = new int[] { 5551303 },
    PlainContent = "A Sample Plain Content for the email",
    SegmentIds = new int[] { },
    Subject = "My Sample Campaign",
    SuppressionGroupId = 7726,
    Title = "My Sample Campaign",
};

var errors = new List<string>();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(campaign);

var response = await sendGridClient.RequestAsync(
                   method: SendGridClient.Method.POST,
                   urlPath: "campaigns",
                   requestBody: json);

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Campaign>(
    response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,
        Error = delegate (object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs args)
            {
                errors.Add(args.ErrorContext.Member.ToString());
                args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
            }
    });

var campaignSendUrl = "campaigns/" + data.Id + "/schedules/now";
var response = await sendGridClient.RequestAsync(
                   method: SendGridClient.Method.POST,
                   urlPath: campaignSendUrl);
```

In the above code, for email body, I have prepared an HTML file which is passed into the "HtmlContent" Property.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PartiStaff</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *, body, td, div {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 13pt;
            color: #404040;
        }

        td {
            padding: 3px 15px 3px 0;
        }

        #container {
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            float: left;
        }

        #contents {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 800px;
        }

        #footer {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 800px;
        }

        img {
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Contact Form</h1>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="contents">            
            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width: 730px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 50px; padding: 15px 0px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold; width: 90px;">First Name:</td>
                    <td>Hello [%first_name%]</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;width: 90px;">Last Name:</td>
                    <td>[%last_name%]</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;width: 90px;">Email:</td>
                    <td>[%email%]</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;width: 90px;" valign="top">Sender Name:</td>
                    <td>[Sender_Name]</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;width: 90px;" valign="top">Sender Address</td>
                    <td>[Sender_Address]</td>
                </tr>                
            </table>

            <p>If you would like to stop receiving these emails <a href="<%unsubscribe%>">click to unsubscribe here</a></p>
            <p>If you would like to stop receiving these emails <a href="<%asm_global_unsubscribe_raw_url%>">click to unsubscribe here</a></p>            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code can create a new Campaign without any errors but it can't send the campaign to the recipients. I found the below errors all time.

> {"errors":[{"field":"unsubscribe_tag","message":"Please add an
>   [unsubscribe] tag to your content. Providing an unsubscribe option is
>   required per commercial email regulations."}]}

Please let me know how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also include the unsubscribe link in the plain text version of the email, for example include this at the end of the plain text mail content:

"Unsubscribe from this list <%asm_group_unsubscribe_raw_url%>"